# Time Complex of double loop function

Tags: loops, math, data-structures, time-complexity, computer-science

I got this question:

```
Func(n)
  for (a = 1; a <= n; a = a * 2)
    for (b = a; b <= n; b = b * 2)
      print a + b
```

I understand the outside loop will run loglog(n), but I have some difficulty understanding how much the inside loop will run.
And also what is the final answer to the Time complexity of this function.
Thank you all.

Comment: Post the code directly, not an image of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe listing down a couple of outputs may help. Here i give an example with `n=10`.

```
a=1: (1+1) (1+2) (1+4) (1+8)
a=2: (2+2) (2+4) (2+8)
a=4: (4+4) (4+8)
a=8: (8+8)
```

You can imagine this a square of edge `roof(log(n))` or `log(n) + 1` if `n` is an exact logarithm, that is not completely "filled". The number of items inside this square is almost the half of the area:

1/2 * log_2(n) * (log_2(n) + 1)

So this will be the asymptotic complexity of your program.